# How to get LockToken of new BrokeredMessage added Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

After sending the **BrokeredMessage** to the queue, like below

```
BrokeredMessage msg = new BrokeredMessage(content);
client.Send(msg);
```

Is there any way to get the value of this `msg.LockToken`?

Comment: You need you get access to the locktoken from the sender ?

Comment: @Thomas, actually i am trying to delete a specific message in the queue. But it seems it is impossible to do it.

Comment: Why do you need to delete this message ? Would you like to explain a little bit more ?

Comment: @Thomas, I use Azure Queue to provide the job to multiple machines. In case user cancel the job, I need to make sure that the job will not be processed if it is still on the queue. First, I am thinking of deleting a specific message on the queue, but it seems to be impossible. I just use another way to handle that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can get LockToken from Message.SystemProperties.LockToken.